# Schedule a method to be called at a specific time on macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to call a method at a given time or interval on macOS. My app sits in the the status bar and just needs to go out to the internet to grab data.

It doesn't need to display that it is doing it or that it finished.

I looked at `NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:`  and `NSUserNotifications`.

The `NSTimer` doesn't feel like the right choice, calling a method `tick` every second just to compare the current time with the time I want to fire the method call.

`NSUserNotificationCenter` I can't seem to find a "application didRecieveNoticication` like there is on iOS.

Is there a way to do what I am wanting? Or is `NSTimer` the way to go?

Comment: Does your method need to be called at a specific time, or just periodically?

Comment: I would like to call it every day at midnight.

Comment: How important is it that your method is called _exactly_ at midnight? If your application isn't open (or the computer isn't running) at midnight, do you need to "catch up", or just skip the call entirely?

Comment: Not on the dot at midnight. If the app was closed and gets reopened, the method gets called to start. If the computer was in standby and wakes up it would need to "catch up" then go back to its normal schedule of checking once a day.

Answer (score 0):

`-[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:]` is probably what you want since it sounds like you already have a relevant run loop since your app is in the menu.  The timer created will be scheduled in the current run loop.  These docs are still fairly relevant: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html

Though if you already know the time you want the timer to fire, you should use that time instead of 1 second interval; polling like that will not be good for battery.

It is worth noting that a timer's fire date is the first moment in time that the timer can fire, and various system level considerations (timer coalescing, etc.) that can contribute to a timer's callback being delayed.

Answer (score 0):

**NSCalendarDayChangedNotification** would suit your needs, it's way more 
    elegant than set up your own timer.

On iOS you can use UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification as 
  well.Either one will work.

```
// This notification is posted through [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
// when the system day changes. Register with "nil" as the object of this
// notification. If the computer/device is asleep when the day changed,
// this will be posted on wakeup. You'll get just one of these if the
// machine has been asleep for several days. The definition of "Day" is
// relative to the current calendar (NSCalendar.currentCalendar) of the
// process and its locale and time zone. There are no guarantees that this
// notification is received by observers in a "timely" manner, same as
// with distributed notifications.

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSNotificationName const NSCalendarDayChangedNotification
NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
```

Answer (score -2):

If it's a regularly scheduled event, cron may work for you

Comment: cron is not appropriate for macOS desktop applications. (Indeed, it isn't available at all to sandboxed apps.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. The question mentions running to "grab data" without any need to display or indicate completion, so it may not need to run as a desktop app (except for sitting in the status bar).